# unknown protocol: c (JDOM a SAXBuilder)

Tags: java, parsing, exception, sax, jdom

I'm using JDOM with SAXBuilder to parse XML files, and I have a problem with a file which is throwing this error :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:986)
    at com.foo.moo.MyClass.getValues(MyClass.java:321)
```

And the line is :

```
Document document = null; 
document = sxb.build(files.elementAt(i)); // This one
```

After doing some research on the internet, I think the error is related to Java 1.6.

What do you think ?

Comment: can you post the XML that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My first guess is that you are loading a local file, like: "c:/mylocalfile.xml"

But this URL does not contain the protocol, like `http://`, `ftp://` or `file://`

Try file://c:/mylocalfile.xml

Comment: Agree.  You can try something like `if(myUrl.getProtocol().equals("c")){myUrl = new URL("file://"+myUrl.toexternalform())}`

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I had space in my folder name which caused this error. Even in case of local files JAVA has the capability of understanding the protocol types.

Comment: Yup, you are so right, and as the OP mentioned this seems to be in issue in Java 1.6 and above only.

Answer (score 0):

I had a space in my file name

i solved it using an InputStream instead of the filename:

works:

```
fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(fis);
```

crashes:

```
Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(filename);
```