# Java URL: Unknown Protocol "C"

Tags: java, file, url

I know there are *similar* questions to this one on SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243550/unknown-protocol-c-jdom-a-saxbuilder) one), however, after reading through the list of "Questions with similar titles", I still feel strongly that this is unique.

I am working with the [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library to generate PDFs from inside a Swing application. iText's `Jpeg` class requires a [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) in its constructor to locate an image/jpg that you want to add to the PDF file.

When I set this `URL` to the absolute file path of my JPG file, I get a `MalformedURLException` claiming **unknown protocol: c** ("c" being the `C:\` drive on my local disk).

Is there any hack/circumvention to this, or do I *have* to host this JPG somewhere and have the `URL` find it over the net?  Here is the code that is failing:

```
try {
    String imageUrl = "C:\Users\MyUser\image.jpg";
    Jpeg image = new Jpeg(new URL(imageUrl));
} catch(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
}
```

**Please note:** The `URL` does properly escape the string (thus "\" are converted to "\ \", etc.).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you be prefixing the file path with file:// ?

Comment: It thinks the `C:` its the protocol.  BTW: You can't use plain \ you need \\ or `/`

Comment: And again you are posting uncompilable code snippets!  What is it about "`String imageUrl = "C:\Users\MyUser\image.jpg";` will not compile", do you *not* understand?!?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You need to turn the path to the image.jpg file into a [file:// URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), like this:

```
String imageUrl = "file:///C:/Users/MyUser/image.jpg";
```

Otherwise it interprets the C as the URL protocol.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to explain *why* the OP's version was incorrect.

Comment: Yes - thank you very much. I like to learn, so its discouraging when other users just want to chastise you instead of help you. Thanks again.

Comment: @Andy Your solution works for me but i want to know the reason behind it. Usually i read a file in java without "file://" and it always works.

Comment: @RajatKhandelwal: I have observed that this error is thrown if the local file path is not appended with "file:///" and the file path actually does not exist on your local disk. If you append "file:///" and then if the file path does not exists, java will plainly show error "Path does not exist". Seems like when the file does not exist and the path is not specified as a file path, java by default considers it as a URL.

Answer (score 13):

Try with

```
String imageUrl = "file:///C:/Users/MyUser/image.jpg";
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
try {
    String imageUrl = "file:///C:/Users/MyUser/image.jpg";
    Jpeg image = new Jpeg(new URL(imageUrl));
} catch(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I was having "%" in my file name. Once I changed it, the file was loaded successfully. So I guess special characters are not allowed in file names, at least in windows.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding

> file:///

before was necessary but not enough.

Maybe I am using badly the Saxon but I also had to set the baseUri to an empty String.
Otherwise it tries to concat the baseUri to the src :

```
FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(xconf.toURI());
builder.setStrictFOValidation(false);
builder.setBaseURI(new URI(""));            
FopFactory fopFactory = builder.build();
```

The code from saxon-he InternalResourceResolver that does the concat :

```
public URI resolveFromBase(URI uri) {
        try {
            return new URL(baseUri.toURL(), uri.toString()).toURI();
        } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return baseUri.resolve(uri);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Searching the file with its directory and adding in the image to assign to the ImageView

```
File file = new File("F:/a.jpg");
Image image = new Image(arquivo.toURI().toString()); //here is magic happens
imageView.setImage(image);
```

Comment: Please do some explanation in how your answer could help OP, and please use only english. Welcome to SO!