# Serving as HTTPS Sonatype Nexus

Tags: ssl, https, jetty, nexus, sonatype

I have installed nexus as a cluster which consist of 3 windows nodes. Right now I want to serve Nexus as HTTPS. When I followed [this documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/security/configuring-ssl#ConfiguringSSL-ServingSSLDirectly), I did everything as suggested but when I run the command

```
nexus.exe /run
```

I'm getting an error that says

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no valid keystore
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:1194)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.load(SslContextFactory.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:396)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:274)
```

My jetty-https.xml config file is like below,

```
...
<New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="certAlias">my-wildcard-cert</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="ssl.etc"/>/keystore.jks</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">changeit</Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">changeit</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="ssl.etc"/>/keystore.jks</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">changeit</Set>
    <Set name="EndpointIdentificationAlgorithm"></Set>
    <Set name="NeedClientAuth"><Property name="jetty.ssl.needClientAuth" default="false"/></Set>
    <Set name="WantClientAuth"><Property name="jetty.ssl.wantClientAuth" default="false"/></Set>
    <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
      <Array type="String">
        <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
      </Array>
    </Set>
  </New>
...
```

I believe my problem with keystore file location but I tried so much and couldn't get any successful result.

I tried like, `<Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property
   name="ssl.etc"/>C:\users\<myusername>\keystore.jks</Set>` and that caused to change error message:

```
2020-03-13 12:40:56,904+0300 ERROR [FelixDispatchQueue] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap - FrameworkEvent ERROR - org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap [65].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2290)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2146)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1373)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:466)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:875)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:478)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:311)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:168)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer.lambda$0(JettyServer.java:117)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:115)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher.start(Launcher.java:131)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher.startAsync(Launcher.java:127)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.LauncherActivator.start(LauncherActivator.java:67)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2240)
        ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(SslContextFactory.java:656)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.newResource(Resource.java:184)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.newResource(Resource.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(SslContextFactory.java:652)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: c
                at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
                at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
                at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.newResource(Resource.java:171)
                ... 25 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: c
                at org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.parseURL(URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.java:373)
                at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:622)
                ... 28 common frames omitted
```

When I searched for **Unknown protocol: c** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474694/java-url-unknown-protocol-c/8474725) it's suggested to use as **file:///C:/Users/MyUser/image.jpg** I tried that too but still got unknown protocol: c error.

How should I fix my jetty-https.xml file?

Thanks in advance
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a fully qualified path name ...

```xml
<Set name="KeyStorePath">C:/users/myusername/keystore.jks</Set>
```

And don't include the extra detail `<Property name="ssl.etc"/>` which just puts the value of the property `"ssl.etc"` in front of your configured path.